# Jtable viewing option

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a hospital management system and I want to achieve the  functionality: 
For example, I am inserting my data into the system as a Doctor and I want only my data to be visible in the jtable and not the other doctors data. How can I do this ? Here is my code:

```
public void FillJTable1 (JTable table){
   PreparedStatement ps;
   ResultSet rs;
   String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM specification where ID=?";

    try {
        ps = my_con.createConnection().prepareStatement(selectQuery);

        rs= ps.executeQuery();
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

        Object [] row;
        while (rs.next()){
            row = new Object [4];

            row[0]= rs.getInt(1);

            row[1]= rs.getString(2);
            row[2]= rs.getString(3);
            row[3]= rs.getString(4);

           tableModel.addRow(row); 
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Doctors.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM specification where ID=?";
```

You have your PreparedStatement but you haven't passed any parameters to the statement.

You need something like:

```
ps.setString( 1, "your doctor id" );
rs= ps.executeQuery();
```

How you get your doctor id is up to you. I guess you would pass a second parameter to your fillJTable1(...) method.

Comment: can you please elaborate more as i am a begginer in coding